# write bitmap to sdcard use byte array?

Tags: android

I want write bitmap to sdcard use byte[] follow code below:
(I wan't use "**Bitmap.compress(...)**" because very slow with .PNG).

```
Bitmap bmp;
// Convert bitmap -> Byte[] 
byte[] byteArray = bitmapToByteArray(bmp); 
// convert byte[] -> inputstream 
InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathFile); 
int b; 
byte[] d = new byte[4096]; 
while ((b = inStream.read(d)) != -1) { 
    fosX.write(d, 0, b); 
} 
// Function convert bitmap -> byte[] 
public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bm) { 
    int bytes = bm.getWidth()*bm.getHeight()*4; 
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
    bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); 
    byte[] array = buffer.array(); 
    return array; 
}
```

File Bitmap after writed is error. Pls

Comment: slow? What does "slow" mean?

Comment: if i use "Bitmap.compress(...)" . speed is 4s - 6s with Bitmap .PNG 1.1Mb. I used device Galaxy Nexus SamSung

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can just write the bytes to a file and expect it to be a functioning Bitmap file. A bitmap file contains other information than just the bytes of the image,like the file header.

You're best bet is to use Bitmap.compress()

```
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(pathFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fos);
```

Also, you could offload the compression to a separate thread to keep your UI responsive.

Comment: compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)

- quality: Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting

Comment: You cant avoid using Bitmap.compress() unless you manually want to write the file header as well. The time taken depends on the file size and also on the storage medium (SD cards can be slow). The only thing I can suggest is to use a separate thread and show the user the progress.